# "the below-identified person": Term for this style and any style guides regarding

Tags: word-order, formality, writing-style, modifiers, above-below

Are there any technical terms to specifically describe the two styles (A and B) below? Also, are there any prescriptive style guides that say which is preferable?

My own preference is for style B below because style A seems to be forcing a pseudo-precise legalistic tone, and I aim for the "plain English" style (i.e., avoiding legalese and bureaucratese), but that is merely my individual feeling.

A

> the above-referenced report
>
> the above-described substance
>
> the below-cited data
>
> the below-identified person

B

> the report referenced above
>
> the substance described above
>
> the data cited below
>
> the person identified below

Comment: A uses an adverb to modify an adjective which modifies a noun. B uses a restrictive relative clause to modify the noun.

Comment: I'd agree with your preference for the relative clauses, except in cases like 'Police found the substance mentioned above down behind the radiator.'

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/163854/whats-the-difference-between-saying-the-passage-above-or-the-above-passage

Answer (score 1):

No, these differences are not strongly associated with any particular style. The "above-referenced" style is sometimes considered slightly more *formal* but that is a description of the style -- it isn't a specific style comes with its own term.

It is completely possible that various styles *do* have a preference on which to use but I don't have a list of such preferences handy.

Answer (score -1):

I would not use either on the grounds that they are not plain English. I would say, for example, "the following data:" or "the report referred to above".

Comment: 'The report referred to above' **is** of OP's 'style B'. And often a simple adjective (for eg 'below-identified') isn't available to pre-modify. You're not addressing the question about choice of construction, merely suggesting different semantics.